# How can I enable adbd during boot on Cyanogenmod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, boot

I am stuck during the boot process, at first before entering the passphrase for `/data` and now at the SIM PIN screen. At this point, adb is inaccessible (normally adbd would start up after unlocking `/data`, etc.).

How can I start `adbd` during boot? This is a CM 10.2 userdebug build for i9300 with `/default.prop` (from initrd) containing:

```
ro.adb.secure=1
ro.secure=1
ro.allow.mock.location=0
ro.debuggable=1
persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb
```

I have also tried the following to no avail:

- Edit `/init.rc`, comment out the `disabled` line for `service adbd`.
- Edit `/init.smdk4x12.usb.rc`, add `start adbd` to the `property:sys.usb.config=mtp` trigger.
- Add `persist.sys.usb.config=adb` to `/default.prop`

Comment: did anyone get this to work? i have a nexus 10, and im trying to maintain usb debugging after device is reset, but it ask for RSA authentication. how can i remove that?
im trying to do all this without touching the device. like run a script to reset the tablet, after its reset usb debugging is still enabled and no rsa pop up crap..so i can continue my script execution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Android 4.2.2, [USB debugging requires authentication], something that is not possible during boot. To disable this, set the following property in default.prop (inside initrd):

```
ro.adb.secure=0
```

Alternatively, copy `~/.android/adbkey.pub` into the initial ramdisk of the boot/recovery image at `/adb_keys`. This preserves the secure feature while granting your key access.

This enables adbd for a short time. It seems that some process is setting `sys.usb.config=mtp`. To work around that, I applied this patch (perhaps only the `start adbd` part is necessary, I have only tested the below):

```
--- init.smdk4x12.usb.rc        2013-10-24 18:47:34.894857300 +0200
+++ init.smdk4x12.usb.rc        2013-10-24 18:47:40.775493943 +0200
@@ -12,10 +12,11 @@
 on property:sys.usb.config=mtp
     write /sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable 0
     write /sys/class/android_usb/android0/idVendor 04e8
-    write /sys/class/android_usb/android0/idProduct 685c
-    write /sys/class/android_usb/android0/functions ${sys.usb.config}
+    write /sys/class/android_usb/android0/idProduct 6860
+    write /sys/class/android_usb/android0/functions ${sys.usb.config},adb
     write /sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable 1
-    setprop sys.usb.state ${sys.usb.config}
+    start adbd
+    setprop sys.usb.state ${sys.usb.config},adb

 on property:sys.usb.config=mtp,adb
     write /sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable 0
```

You won't be able to get root (`su`) through this. For that, set:

```
ro.secure=0
```

Updating the initramfs block, the initramfs header field and the SHA1 ID (header) of the boot.img is not in the scope of this answer.

Comment: On modern lineage, this is automatically done for you with `eng` variant builds e.g. `brunch lineage_us996-eng`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple one command to get going without stuck!

`# setprop persist.sys.usb.config mtp,adb`

Awaiting your response!

Comment: This will not work during boot (e.g. before disk encryption is unlocked), though it may become active once Android begins to start.