# How to enable adb in bootloader mode?

Tags: adb, boot, bootloader

Is it possible to enable `adb` in bootloader mode? I've already managed to enable it at boot following [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55674/how-can-i-enable-adbd-during-boot-on-cyanogenmod), but couldn't figure out yet how to enable it in bootloader mode (if it is even possible?).

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Afraid that's not possible. Strictly speaking, Bootloader hasn't even anything to do with Android at all. You can have ADB with the "normal system" booted, and with Recovery (as both are running Android). But in Bootloader, there's no Android running (think of it as kind of boot-menu with update options, or "BIOS mode").

Comment: Does that count for download mode on Samsung devices too? I understand it's Samsung's version of bootloader mode; am I right? Is there any possibility to start a shell in bootloader/download mode similar to `adb shell`?

Comment: AFAIK yes, that's how Sammy calls it (they've got to do things different always, no idea why).

Comment: Do you know whether there is any way to start a shell in bootloader/download mode similar to `adb shell`?

Comment: As said, there is none in bootloader mode. As the name suggests, this is the mode prior to loading any OS. No OS, no shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible – as in Bootloader mode, there's no real OS loaded yet (see [XDA Wiki](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Bootloader) and [AddictiveTips](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/what-is-bootloader-and-how-to-unlock-bootloader-on-android-phones-complete-guide/)). Quoting from [AddictiveTips](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/what-is-bootloader-and-how-to-unlock-bootloader-on-android-phones-complete-guide/):

> In literal terms, bootloader is code that is executed before any Operating System starts to run. The concept of bootloaders is universal to virtually all Operating systems that inculcates operating systems on your PC, laptop, smartphones, and other such devices. Bootloaders basically package the instructions to boot operating system kernel […]
>
> Every Android phone has a bootloader ***that instructs the operating system kernel to boot normally.***

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

As there isn't any OS running yet in this mode (especially no Android), there's no ADB that can be run. That applies all the same to "Download mode" with Samsung devices, or HBoot with HTC (just different names for the same thing).