# How to enable USB Debugging from recovery mode?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, usb-debugging, broken-screen

My phone screen broke. I can't see anything, and the touch screen doesn't work. I can't buy a new phone, so I'm not looking into backing up my data, I want to be able to use it from my pc.
I have a Motorola Moto G2 running LineageOS 14.1, and TWRP custom recovery.

Until now I have been able to use my phone with from my PC using [Vysor](https://vysor.io), because I previously had USB debugging activated. However, **I accidently deactivated it and now I'm stuck out**.

I can access via ADB through recovery and **already have investigated how to activate USB debugging** again from the shell using these sources:

- [How to enable USB Debugging in Android if forgotten pattern for screen-unlock?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112040/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-android-if-forgotten-pattern-for-screen-unlock)
- [Can I enable USB debugging using adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120394/can-i-enable-usb-debugging-using-adb)
- [Broken screen while debug mode was disabled. How can I re-enable adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12834/broken-screen-while-debug-mode-was-disabled-how-can-i-re-enable-adb)
- [Enable USB debugging through Clockworkmod with adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326806/enable-usb-debugging-through-clockworkmod-with-adb/13332721#13332721)
- [How can I enable adbd during boot on Cyanogenmod?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55674/how-can-i-enable-adbd-during-boot-on-cyanogenmod)
- [Manually enable adb debugging from recovery](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2335799)
- [How to authorize adb service from boot](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.b2g/epQ6qhIFZ50)

But **none of these solutions have worked for me.**

Here's a brief summary of everything I've tried:

- I've set the content of /data/property/persist.sys.usb.config to `mtp,adb`
- I've edited /data/system/users/0/settings_global.xml, setting `adb_enabled`, `verifier_verify_adb_installs` and `development_settings_enabled` to `1`
- I've added these lines to /system/build.prop:

  `persist.service.adb.enable=1
  persist.service.debuggable=1
  persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb`
- I've used the following `setprop` commands:

  `setprop persist.service.adb.enable 1
  setprop persist.service.debuggable 1
  setprop persist.sys.usb.config mtp,adb`

But when I reboot, I still can't see my device when I run `adb devices`

Not only that, but then **everytime I reboot to TWRP recovery again, I notice that some changes are reversed:**

- /data/property/persist.sys.usb.config content only says `adb`
- /data/system/users/0/settings_global.xml remains almost intact but `adb_enabled` is back to `0` again
- When I run `getprop` to all of the properties I've setted before using `setprop`, it returns an empty string (which makes me suspect that the changes I've been making to /system/build.prop are being completely ignored)

**It's as if everytime the phone boots, the system loads some default configuration and reverses some of the changes I've made and USB debugging remains deactivated**. Am I missing something? I really not know what else to do.

Comment: Keep in mind that you are running the recovery OS, not the main OS. Also consider that certain paths may be loaded from a RAM-disk image, there editing has no persistent effect.

Comment: Then, where should I make the changes necessary for the main OS to apply my parameters? Is there any file which is being loaded from boot that I can edit to activate usb debugging?

Comment: May be you should elaborate first why you need adb on your main OS. From your description it seems like you already have adb access from the recovery rom and it looks like you have access to your data partition. Therefore you can backup your data and migrate it to a new phone.

Comment: Because right now I can't afford a new phone. I'm not looking for a backup of my data, what I'm looking for is to be able to use my phone from the computer. As I said, I use an app named Vysor that mirrors the screen and lets me manipulate it, but for it to work, USB Debugging must be activated.